# How to simplify opamps in circuits for limit analysis

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, circuit-analysis, filter, high-frequency

I know that when simplifying electronic circuits for limit analysis you can e.g. replace capacitors with closed lines and coils with open lines. 
e.g.:

[image]

the equivalen at high frequencies would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCNu4R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But what about opamps?

e.g:

What would be the simplified version of that at lower and higher frequencies?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fldhjH.png)</sup>

Comment: If you replace C1 with a short, you'll have a circuit you should recognize immediately, without changing the op-amp to anything but an ideal op-amp.

Comment: @ThePhoton. This is a simple integrator, but if the OP wants the effects of C1 ranging from near zero to infinite capacitance, then op-amp single-pole filters apply. Else the OP's question is a bit too broad in scope. You cannot take any parts out of this circuit. It would stop functioning (in any normal way).

Comment: @Sparky256 I only want to see how the circuit would behave at high frequencies (near infinity) and at low frequencies (DC).

Comment: @J.Doe. Then The Photon already has your answer. Surf the internet on single-pole op-amp filters for the details of each extremes. Way too much data to place it all on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

You don't replace the op-amp with anything. If the circuit provides negative feedback to the op-amp, you use the ideal op-amp rules to solve the circuit.

In this case, if you go to high frequency, replace the capacitor with a short. You'll see an op-amp circuit that you should recognize easily.

If you go to low frequency, replace the capacitor with an open. Now you have no negative feedback, so you're left with the open-loop response of the op-amp. Typically, a second resistor (R2>>R1) is placed in parallel with C1 to avoid this problem.